# Using Amazon SES through the AWS SDK for Java

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I want to send emails via an AWS account using SES in my SpringBoot application. But the issue is that I do not have the permission to generate access keys in that account. Neither can I create IAM users. I can only create and use IAM roles. But everywhere I looked mentions ways that need the access keys to be able to send emails programmatically, which I don't have. Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use the Java SES API, you do require an IAM User that has permission to use the SES Service. Then you **require the access key and secret key** for this IAM User. Without these values, you cannot successfully make an AWS Service call using the AWS SDK for Java.

This is mentioned in the ***AWS SDK for Java Developer Guide*** here:

[Get started with the AWS SDK for Java 2.x](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/get-started.html)

**Update**:

As you do not have the access key and secret key, you need to create a new **IAM User**. When you create a new IAM User, you will be given new access key and secret key values. Write these values down and use those. Also - make sure you IAM User has permission to use Amazon SES. See [Create an IAM user](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/get-started.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering! I suppose it cannot be done then. Also, from what I read IAM roles don't have access keys associated with them. Am I mistaken in that?

Comment: See update that i posted

Comment: Aren't IAM Role and IAM user two different things? I don't have access to creating IAM users but only IAM roles, and IAM roles don't seem to have access keys.

Comment: If you cannot create a new User, talk to the admin of this AWS Account and let them know you need a new IAM User and get those key values.

Comment: Got it. Thanks!